# Setting Python 32-bit and 64-bit mode for virtualenv on OSX

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I have a python virtual environment for the sole purpose of using wxPython. wxPython on Mac uses the Carbon framework, which hasn't been built in 64-bit. Therefore, I can't run wxPython on a mac with Python running 64-bit. Is there a way to tell my installation to always run 32-bit? It's getting annoying having to use `arch -i386` every time.

Comment: Please see this similar (identical?) question and its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663852

Comment: This one has a slightly different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `virtualenv`, there's an argument `-p` to specify the `PYTHON_EXE` to use for this environment.